# CMSIS_OS V2/FreeRTOS HardFault

Tags: c, arm, stm32, freertos, cmsis

i am writing a code using STM32CubeMx generated code with CMSIS-OSV2/FreeRTOS. I am sending a structure with Queues between tasks. In some point i am having a Hard Fault.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ZqY.png)
I show my code below.

```
void pmt_task_RX_uart_func(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN pmt_task_RX_uart_func */
    char msg[60];
    Fuente_MPPC_C11204 Pmt_AUX;
    osStatus_t eventPMT_buffer;
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
        eventPMT_buffer = osMessageQueueGet(PMT_Buffer_QueueHandle, &msg, NULL, osWaitForever);   // wait for message
        if(eventPMT_buffer==osOK){
            //MENSAJE PUESTO EN LA QUEUE
            osStatus_t eventPMT_struct = osMessageQueueGet(PMT_Struct_QueueAUXHandle, &Pmt_AUX, NULL, osWaitForever);
            if(eventPMT_struct==osOK){
                //MENSAJE PUESTO EN LA QUEUE
                strcpy((char*) Pmt_AUX.cmd_recieved_buffer, msg);
                Pmt_AUX = hps_recivecmd(&Pmt_AUX);
                osStatus_t eventSen = osMessageQueuePut(PMT_RX_QueueHandle, &Pmt_AUX, 0U, osWaitForever);
                if(eventPMT_struct==osOK){
                    //MENSAJE PUESTO EN LA QUEUE
                    
                    osThreadYield(); 
                } else if(eventPMT_struct==osErrorResource){
                //QUEUE ESTA LLENA
                } else if(eventPMT_struct==osErrorTimeout){
                //NO SE PUDO PONER EL MENSAJE EN LA QUEUE
                }   else if(eventPMT_struct==osErrorParameter){
                // parameter mq_id is NULL or invalid, non-zero timeout specified in an ISR.
                }
            } else if(eventPMT_struct==osErrorResource){
                //QUEUE ESTA LLENA
            } else if(eventPMT_struct==osErrorTimeout){
                //NO SE PUDO PONER EL MENSAJE EN LA QUEUE
            }   else if(eventPMT_struct==osErrorParameter){
                // parameter mq_id is NULL or invalid, non-zero timeout specified in an ISR.
            }
        } else if(eventPMT_buffer==osErrorResource){
            //QUEUE ESTA LLENA
        } else if(eventPMT_buffer==osErrorTimeout){
            //NO SE PUDO PONER EL MENSAJE EN LA QUEUE
        }   else if(eventPMT_buffer==osErrorParameter){
            // parameter mq_id is NULL or invalid, non-zero timeout specified in an ISR.
        }
  }
  /* USER CODE END pmt_task_RX_uart_func */
}
```

As you can see i receive two queues, the first one is a char[60] and the second a structure PMT_RX_QueueHandle. Both messages i receive it correctly. But then while debugging here it jumps to a hardfault error handler.

```
osStatus_t eventSen = osMessageQueuePut(PMT_RX_QueueHandle, &Pmt_AUX, 0U, osWaitForever);
                if(eventPMT_struct==osOK){
                    //MENSAJE PUESTO EN LA QUEUE
                    
                    osThreadYield(); 
                }
```

All task have the same priority and the same stack size = 500(words) = 500*4.
Here is the code of my structure

```
/*Typedef start*/
typedef enum
{
    HST = 0,
    HRT,
    HPO,
    HGS,
    HGV,
    HGC,
    HGT,
    HFI,
    HGN,
    HOF,
    HON,
    HRE,
    HCM,
    HSC,
    HRC,
    HBV
}hps_cmd_t;


typedef struct Fuente_MPPC_C11204{
    
    UART_HandleTypeDef * uart;
    uint8_t cmd_recieved_buffer[60];
    uint8_t buffer_PMT_INDEX;
    char data2send[32];
    hps_cmd_t comSend;      //Este es el comando que envio(en formato hps_cmd_t)
    char cmdAwait[5];       //Este es el comando que estoy esperando recibir
    uint8_t statusUart;     //Si recibo la rta del comando correctamente esta en 0, en caso contrario esta en 1
    char error[5];              //Info del error de Fuente
    
    char secondCoefT1[5];   //Coeficientes de Temp
    char secondCoefT2[5];   //
    char FirstCoefT1[5];    //
    char FirstCoefT2[5];    //
    char RefVoltage[5];     //Vb de la fuente
    char RefTemp[5];            //Tb de la fuente
    
    char status[5];             //Status de la fuente
    char OutVoltage[5];     //Voltage de salida
    char OutCurrent[5];     //Corriente de la fuente
    char MPPCTemp[5];           //TEMP de la fuente
    
    char deviceName[17];    //Datos de la fuente
    char Version[17];           //      
    char BuildDate[12];     //
    char SerialNum[17];     //
    
    uint8_t mode;                           //Compensacion de temp activado o desactivado
    char FunctionSettings[5];   //funciones de la fuente

}Fuente_MPPC_C11204;
```

And here the definitions of the Queues

```
  comman_tQueueHandle = osMessageQueueNew (1, sizeof(command_t), &comman_tQueue_attributes);

  /* creation of PMT_Struct_Queue */
  PMT_Struct_QueueHandle = osMessageQueueNew (1, sizeof(Fuente_MPPC_C11204), &PMT_Struct_Queue_attributes);

  /* creation of PMT_Struct_QueueAUX */
  PMT_Struct_QueueAUXHandle = osMessageQueueNew (1, sizeof(Fuente_MPPC_C11204), &PMT_Struct_QueueAUX_attributes);

  /* creation of PMT_RX_Queue */
  PMT_RX_QueueHandle = osMessageQueueNew (1, sizeof(Fuente_MPPC_C11204), &PMT_RX_Queue_attributes);

  TxRaspBuffQueueHandle = osMessageQueueNew (1, sizeof(uint8_t[100]), &TxRaspBuffQueue_attributes);

  /* creation of RxRaspBuffQueue */
  RxRaspBuffQueueHandle = osMessageQueueNew (1, sizeof(uint8_t[100]), &RxRaspBuffQueue_attributes);
    
    /* creation of PMT_Buffer_Queue */
  PMT_Buffer_QueueHandle = osMessageQueueNew (1, sizeof(uint8_t[100]), &PMT_Buffer_Queue_attributes);
```

I think that it could be something about the size of the queue or stack size but i dont see why. Im missing something else.

Comment: i keep debugging and i notice this: ive commented the code of the task and i keep only the first get message and the hardFault keeps going. Maybe this comes from something else.

Comment: Your error indicates a memory alignment fault. You've tried to read (or write) something like an `int` from an address that is not a multiple of 4, probably. `hps_cmd_t comSend;` in your structure would be a contender (if the structure was packed). Consider moving that up in the structure, above the `chars` that precede it. It's good practice to order things in a structure based on their alignment requirements, highest at the top, if you have the freedom to do so.